# Units in indefinite quaternionic algebra

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, computational-number-theory, shimura-varieties, quaternion-algebras

This is the opposite to my last [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250753/finite-group-of-units-in-quaternion-orders) case.

Let $F$ be a totally real number field, $R$ is a quaternion algebra over $F$ unramified in at least one infinite place of $F$. Let $\mathcal{O}⊂R$ be an order.

Can I explicitly compute the rank and generators of the group of units $\mathcal{O}^{\times}$ in terms of, say, some basis in $R/F$?

It seems that the rank is related to the corresponding Shimura curve, but I do not see how this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by rank of this noncommutative group?

Comment: @Aurel Just the minimal number of generators

Comment: Ok, then in the Fuchsian case (only one split real place) maybe you can compute the rank without actually computing generators, using standard presentations of Fuchsian groups. I think this is also discussed in Voight's article I mention below.

Answer (score 4):

If there is only one split real place, you can use the algorithm described by John Voight in *Computing fundamental domains for Fuchsian groups*. This algorithm is available in Magma.